# Strange spikes in the signal ModelSim VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I'm working on a final project for school and this is my first time working with VHDL in Quartus and ModelSIM. It's supposed to be a control for an elevator that services three floors. I have these strange spikes in a few signals, and I can't seem to find their source.

The one problem I have is a spike in a signal that feeds to an up/down counter that shows the current floor. When it stops at a floor, it ends up counting one additional time and going either one floor too high or one floor too low, while the next floor display seems to show the same floor just fine until another floor is called. The next floor display comes from an FSM, while the current floor display is from an up/down counter.

It's a bit complex to post everything here, so I'm just going to post the waveform for now in case someone's come across this signal spike thing and it ends up being a minor error/easy fix.!

[image: waveform]

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity FSM_Elevador is
    port (Up_Down, Igual, Reset, Clock: in std_logic;
            Andar_Dif: out std_logic
            );
end FSM_Elevador;

architecture FSM_beh of FSM_Elevador is
    type Elev_States is (Start, Wait_State, Pulse_State);
    signal Current_State, Next_State: Elev_States;
    signal RST, CLK, Sig_Andar_Dif, Cont_Mesmo_Andar: std_logic;

begin

RST <= Reset;
CLK <= Clock;

process(RST, CLK)
begin
    if RST = '0' then
         Current_State <= Start;
    elsif CLK'event and  CLK = '1' then
         Current_State <= Next_State;
    end if;
end process;

process(Current_State, Igual)
begin
    case Current_State is
        when Start =>
            Next_State <= Wait_State;
        when Wait_State =>
            if Igual = '1' then
                Next_State <= Wait_State;
                Sig_Andar_Dif <= '0';
            else
                Next_State <= Pulse_State;
                Sig_Andar_Dif <= '1';
            end if;
        when Pulse_State =>
            if Igual = '1' then
                Sig_Andar_Dif <= '0';
                Next_State <= Wait_State;
            else
                Sig_Andar_Dif <= '0';
                Next_State <= Pulse_State;
            end if;
    end case;
end process;
Andar_Dif <= Sig_Andar_Dif;
end FSM_beh;
```

**fru1tbat:** I use the Elev_pulse to make the counter go up or down once, and yes it enters the counter as a clock. It was suggested by the professor.

**Edit:** sorry that was the wrong code earlier. Andar_Dif is what sends out the signal that ends up going to the component that has Elev_Pulse

Comment: Post the code where you assign Elev_Pulse.  I bet you're assigning it with an OR gate?

Comment: Are you sure those spikes are causing your extra counts? Generally they wouldn't, unless you're using them as clocks (which it doesn't look like you intend to, as you appear to have a master clock), or doing something else that's not obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the reassignment of Clock and Reset to CLK and RST and just use the signals from the port directly. That is creating a delta cycle delay which is the cause of these kind of spikes. It looks like you have resets with different delays in the design which can also complicate matters. If the removal of the indirection doesn't clear things up you need to scrutinize the ordering of when events are generated on signals and when they are processed.

The outputs from your state machine are unregistered which is also potentially involved. Consider reworking the FSM so that all outputs are registered. This is a better design practice in general as it ensures that you don't have unknown combinational delays affecting downstream logic.

Comment: I got rid of the reassignments of clocks and resets (there were a couple in the whole project). I'm not sure whether I saw this from the prof or his handouts or where I got it from. Anyways, it turned the 100 ps pulses into instantaneous pulses. wasn't what I was expecting, but now the elevator seems to work properly. I wonder if this has to do with the fact that I'm only doing RTL simulations.

Comment: You still have delta-cycle delay issues in the design. The asynchronous outputs from the FSM are likely involved. As a quick hack you can try putting a little more delay on them with `foo_delay <= foo after 1 ps` to see what happens. The spikes mean that you have a timing hazard that could be a problem post-synthesis.

Comment: Yeah, I may have to revert the changes to turn in the project, because the way it was it would move between floors, but now it will do the first two calls, and then I have an issue with the resets on the flip-flops that take the button presses. Currently the resets permanently disable the buttons after the first call, and I realize registers would be useful here, but unfortunately I don't have time to really do this project well. I'll post back on what happens, I really appreciate your input!!

Comment: I appreciate your help, and it's unfortunate that I won't be finishing this project. However, I did learn something, significance of the spikes.